# Cannot use namespace 'ThemeDefinition' as a type in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create a custom theme for Vuetify v3.0.0-alpha.10
This is my vuetify.ts plugin file

```js
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
import "vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass";
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/lib/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/lib/directives";

const defaultLightTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    surface: "#FFFFFF",
    primary: "#6200EE",
    "primary-darken-1": "#3700B3",
    secondary: "#03DAC6",
    "secondary-darken-1": "#018786",
    error: "#B00020",
    info: "#2196F3",
    success: "#4CAF50",
    warning: "#FB8C00",
  },
};

export default createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: "defaultLightTheme",
    themes: {
      defaultLightTheme,
    },
  },
});
```

But I get this error:
[Cannot use namespace 'ThemeDefinition' as a type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krLm3.png)

I copied the example of Vuetify docs:
[Vuetify docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmzKu.png)

Any idea to solve this problem? Thanks and greets

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: I tried with the first anwer and my project is now working, but I think I should wait for a stable version of Vue 3 nad Vuetify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had similar problem
i ended up doing the following:

```js
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/lib/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

export default createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'myCustomTheme',
    themes: {
      myCustomTheme: {
        dark: false,
        colors: {
          background: '#FFFFFF'
          // more colors
        },
        variables: {} //ADD AN EMPTY OBJECT
     }
   }
  }
})
```

please, pay attention to the **variables** field - that is currently [a known bug in Vuetify 3](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13914)